# Numpy Install on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, python-2.7, numpy

I have been trying to install numpy on my Mac OSX for the last 2 days. I have installed Homebrew as well, and ran the command-

```
pip install numpy
```

which gives me the following output-

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

then I ran the command-

```
import  numpy as np
```

which gives me

```
-bash: import: command not found
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try launching python first before typing `import numpy as np`??

Answer (score 2):

If you run `import numpy` from the command line, you will get an error:

```
$ import numpy as np
-bash: import: command not found
```

You need to start Python, and then type the import statement within the Python interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(5)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```